# Call method in android ndk library from C#

Tags: c#, android-ndk

So, I have this shared object file from an android ndk build. I have different builds for ARM, X86 etc.
The lib contains a method which takes a byte array as input and returns an integer. I have no interest in figuring out what it does, but I would like to call this from a C# application. Preferrably the C# application would run on the windows platform, but I understand this might be tricky.

I know the method declaration but are curious on what options I have here.

Right now I run this code on Ubuntu using wsl in windows.
I have tried to use NativeLibrary to load the .so file and it seems to be missing some other library, which I do have in the same directory.

When loading it this way:

```
NativeLibrary.Load("/mnt/c/Users/Jonas/Downloads/test/bin/Debug/net7.0/x86_64/libstufflib.so", typeof(StuffLib).Assembly, DllImportSearchPath.AssemblyDirectory)
```

I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'StuffLib' threw an exception.
 ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library '/mnt/c/Users/Jonas/Downloads/test/bin/Debug/net7.0/x86_64/libstufflib.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider using a tool like strace. If you're using glibc, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable:
/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.5//mnt/c/Users/Jonas/Downloads/test/bin/Debug/net7.0/x86_64/libstufflib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
liblog.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It seems to me as it does find the libstufflib.so and then fails on the liblog.so dependency?